# Ruby on rails, How to use Nokogiri to get a id in tags in XML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

recently I meet a issue with Nokogiri. how could I get the id in a tag?

for example, there is a xml file, and inside the code like this :

```
<channel id="firstchannel">
    <display-name>channel name </display-name>
    <icon src="pngpath"/>
</channel>
```

how could I get the id "firstchannel"?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to locate the element you want.
For example, if

```
<icon src="pngpath"/>
```

is relatively unique and we use it as an anchor.
Then the code would be:

```
#require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML File.read "file.xml"  #Read xml file and parse into Nokogiri object
ic = doc.css('icon[src="pngpath"]') #locate icon element
theId = ic.first.parent.get_attribute :id  #Find the id

p theId
#=> "firstchannel"
```

Depends on different situation, you might need different approach to find the 
right thing you want.

Comment: How is it `HTML`? What version of HTML contains tags `channel`, `display-name` and `icon`?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin  Thanks, updated. I think there're no difference in this case, am I wrong about this? Could you please tell me if there's any harm in what I did?

Comment: No idea; it just looked semantically incorrect to me and I pointed that out.

Comment: @Tiw, could you tell me if I want to get the value of src, what should I do ?

Comment: I thought it was the same , but I have a error like that the value is null.

if I do xpath again , it will show 

undefined method `get_attribute' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:0x00007fa37508d3b8> (NoMethodError)

Comment: @Yuting  `ic.first.get_attribute :src` or `ic.first['src']`, ic is not a simple element but a "group".

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(info_html)
channel = doc.css('channel')[0]['id']
```

Checkout more about basic Nokogiri [here in this link](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/)

Comment: How is it `HTML`? What version of HTML contains tags `channel`, `display-name` and `icon`?

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't check if the `info_html` string is a valid HTML, he just expects HTML format, so with Yuting You XML example will work just fine. You also can try in your console.